# Fetch records with outer join query

Tags: oracle, outer-join

I have a situation where current implementation joins 2 tables to fetch records as below
however there is a case that employee and address as versioned entities

```
    create table employee (
  empid int primary key,
  VER_ID int,
  ADId int 
);

create table ADDRESS(
  ADId int not null ,
  VER_ID int,
  AD_AGGREGATE VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)  
);

insert into employee values (500,12,100);
insert into employee values (501,13,101);
insert into employee values (502,22,102);
insert into employee values (503,23,103);

insert into ADDRESS values (100,12,'abc');
insert into ADDRESS values (101,13,'bc');
insert into ADDRESS values (102,22,,'def');
insert into ADDRESS values (103,-1,'ghi');

I wish to fetch all records by joining employee and Address along with the ver_id =-1 which means all eomployees with id 500 to 503 should appear in response as below 
currently it does not show Address record with 103 and ver_id=-1 I want that also should be part of response

select * from ADDR_INFO ai ,ADDRESS a
where ai.ADId=a.ADId (+)
        and ai.VER_ID=a.VER_ID (+);

Result set should look like below 
500 12  100     100 12 abc
501 13  101     101 13 bc
502 22  102     102 22 def
503 23  103     103 -1 ghi
```

I tried with or condition but its not working as below

```
select * from employee ai ,ADDRESS a
where ai.ADId=a.ADId (+)
        and (ai.VER_ID=a.VER_ID (+) or a.VER_ID=-1 );
```

Comment: ADDRESS has 3 column but you are inserting 4 value. on the other hand I do not understand (+) in the query.

Comment: corrected Address insert statement. (+) is outer join and that is the existing query I want result set to have union of both tables with join of ADId and Ver_id However ver_id  may not match some times .Actually this is a generated query in my framework and I have few records with matching ver_id with parent and some are simply have ver_id=-1 in child  (i.e. Address) table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to join address and employee to show all record with ver_id = -1. So you can can write this:

```
select a.empid,a.adid,a.ver_id,b.ad_aggregate  from employee a join  address b  on a.ADId=b.ADId;
```

Is it your mean?

Comment: Not exactly here scenario is employee has multiple addresses and both employee & addresses are versioned entities and background utility is deleting duplicate records from address table and inserts new record and sets ver_id=-1 so I want both type of records in result set i.e. with ADId & ver_id combination along with records only matching to ADID and relax ver_id match hence the 'or a.VER_ID=-1' . Also select * from employee ai ,ADDRESS a where ai.ADId=a.ADId (+) and ai.VER_ID=a.VER_ID (+)   is the framwerok query and I with enhance it by adding some more clauses

Comment: I edited the response. Is it okay?

Comment: Yes it looks good but lets see how it works for my real time scenario .